# Confused about debounce function in javascript and " Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, addeventlistener, debouncing

I'm trying to learn to implement debouncing in javascript, however I got an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined". May I know how to fix it?

Also, I'm still so confused about:

```
function debounce (func, wait) {
  var timeoutID;
  return function () {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    timeoutID = setTimeout(func, wait);
  }
}
```

I know the main idea of debounce is to trigger the function when we haven't move the mouse for 2 seconds, if we moved inside the 2 seconds, the counter will be clear and re count from the start again, but I'm still confused about the code. Why we set the timeoutID variable at the beginning of the function? How does this be identified as the timeoutID we set inside the returned function? why we then "return" the timer function? 
When it's first called, var timeoutID just initiate this variable with no value, then how can the clearTimeout(timeoutID) use this variable with no value?
Thank you so much!

```
function debounce (func, wait) {
  var timeoutID;
  return function () {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    timeoutID = setTimeout(func, wait);
  }
}
function test(e) {
  console.log(e.clientX);
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', debounce(test,2000));
```

Comment: The function returned from `debounce` is not accepting the `e` passed into it, and is not passing it on to the `func`

Comment: `clearTimeout` is called when the callback is invoked, to clear any preceeding timeout that has not transpired.  If one doesn't exist, it doesn't matter.  `clearTimeout` will not error.  After that, you create the timeout to allow it to start the duration wait before the callback is invoked.

Comment: @Taplar Thank you so much! May I know how to fix it? And may I know why we return the timeout function instead just run the code inside the debounce function like var timeoutID;clearTimeout(timeoutID); timeoutID = setTimeout(func, wait); ?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but this looks like an odd implementation of debouncing, to say the least. Even when fixed, this will log the mouse X position as it was 2 seconds ago. Debouncing as I know it uses a boolean value in the closure to track whether enough time has elapsed since the last time the function was called, and only calls it again when that boolean is `true`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you so much!

Comment: this: _why we then "return" the timer function?_ - The `.addEventListener()` method takes a function _reference_ as the callback argument. In this case, the `debounce()` function is _executed_ at the time the event handler is established. The result of that operation is that the returned anonymous function get set as the callback for the `.addEventListener()` method. Now, each time the mouse moves, the anonymous function is executed.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thank you so much! So we return the timer is because addEventListener need a function as the second parameter right? Just like if we don't use debounce we should use test function as the second parameter right? document.addEventListener('mousemove',test); But may I know why we var timeoutID outside the timer function? Thank you so much!

Comment: it's is outside so that there is only ever one version of it. It is in a closure created by the `debounce` function.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thank you so much! So inner function clearTimeout(timeoutID); can always get the variable because of closure right? May I know how this timeoutID changed through calls?  Is it right that for the first call of debounce, var timeoutID; makes timeoutID undefined, then clearTimeout(timeoutID); is not working and then  the  timeoutID = setTimeout(func, wait); makes a new value of 1 for the timeoutID? Then mouse moved within 2 seconds, debounce function is triggered again, so var timeoutID; will be run again? var timeoutID; will always be run when we move the mouse?

Comment: yes. That is correct.

Comment: @RandyCasburn But what would be the difference if we put the  var timeoutID inside the return function as the first line? Thank you so much!

Comment: You would lose reference to the _previous_ use of the variable. That's what closures are for.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thank you so much! So the reference is for auto increase the id of timeoutID? The first call the timeoutID is undefined, then after the second call it's 1, then after the second call it's 2? But I'm kind of confused since I every debounce call is independent when we move the mouse, the returned function is a one time use, why and how this reference help?

Comment: Let's finish this by me recommend you learn how to use the debugger tools within the browser to step through the code, line-by-line and watch precisely what occurs when.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to call the callback with the arguments the event gets.  So it is transparent to the event handler if it was called directly or from a debounce.

```js
function debounce (callback, delay) {
  var timeout;
  
  return function () {
    var originalArguments = arguments;
    
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => callback.apply(this, originalArguments), delay);
  }
}

function test(e) {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(e.target);
}

document.getElementById('thing').addEventListener('click', debounce(test, 2000));
```

```html
<a href="#" id="thing" data-thing="test">Click Me Repeatedly</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!